# How to connect with Jsoup and a private SSL certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, jsoup, htmlunit

I have a trouble with Jsoup and login to a website with private secure certificate.
I'll try to use HtmlUnit and all works fine, in this way:

```
public class TestHtmlUnit {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestHtmlUnit.class);
    private WebClient webClient;
    private PropertiesManagement management;

    private void loginForm() throws Exception {
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(management.getHomeURL());
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("form1");
        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("btnAccedi");
        final HtmlTextInput usernameField = form.getInputByName("txtUtente");
        final HtmlPasswordInput passwordField = form.getInputByName("txtPwd");
        usernameField.setValueAttribute(management.getUsername());
        passwordField.setValueAttribute(management.getPassword());
        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
        printPage(page2);

        logger.debug("End!!");
    }

    public void printPage(HtmlPage page) {
        WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
        String content = response.getContentAsString();
        logger.debug("HTML SOURCE: " + content);
    }

    public void init() {
        try {
            webClient = new WebClient();
            management = new PropertiesManagement();
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setSSLClientCertificate(management.getFilePathURL(), management.getPassword(), management.getSSLProtocol());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestHtmlUnit testHtmlUnit = new TestHtmlUnit();
        testHtmlUnit.init();
        testHtmlUnit.loginForm();
    }

}
```

but when i try to connecting at the same site with the same certificate with Jsoup, i get a response "Certificate not imported correctly".

How i do this?

If you ask "Why need to use jsoup if u can use htmlunit?" (good question), my answer is "because i am unable to navigate a lot of popup page with htmlUnit :D!"

Answer (score 1):

I solve myself:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(management.getFilePath());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(management.getSSLProtocol());
ks.load(fin, management.getPassword().toCharArray());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "certificate.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", management.getPassword()); 

Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(management.getHomeURL()).
        timeout(5000).ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).execute();
 res = Jsoup.connect(management.getHomeURL()).timeout(5000).execute();
Document post = res.parse();

System.out.println(post.html());
```

now need a little of optimization... but it's next step :D